# How to read a fortran fort.# where # is a number file in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, load

I have an output from a fortran code that looks like this:

[image]

The results are stored in a fort.# where # is a number in general file. How can I load this file in python where each column is a different array or a column of a dataframe?

Code I am using but doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
number_of_integers =1
with open(file_location,'r') as f:
    header = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.int, count=number_of_integers)
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.float32)
```

I have  also tried:

```
data  = np.fromfile(file_location,dtype = np.float32)
new_data = data.reshape() # something here but I can't read the shape
```

You can find the file here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ohC2sHxs2M211HxIHd7yH2_Y5l5c1pQA?usp=sharing

Comment: Access denied on that Google file but you might want to look at [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: @DrBwts here is the file again I am sorry https://www.dropbox.com/s/73mcs1lzc1yybbn/fort.21?dl=0. Can you read a non .csv file  with this command? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your files are all of the same format & you dont want the header then the following reads your file and puts it into a 2D numpy array,

```
import numpy as np    

my_data = []
with open('fort.21') as fort:
    
    for idx, row in enumerate(fort):
        
        if idx > 0:
            row_split = row.split('  ')[1:]
            temp_list = [float(r_s) for r_s in row_split]
            my_data.append(temp_list)
            
my_data = np.asarray(my_data)
```

Comment: @ DrBwts  Very Helpful !! One more question in the general case that not all are on the same format. For example this file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/64otwif93y0848d/fort.30?dl=0. Do you know of a way to read this one?

Comment: @Jokerp It appears to have been saved in binary format, so without more information about the format I cant help you sorry.